# как сохранить файлы имея его uri

Tags: android

с помощью кода

```
private val pickPhoto = registerForActivityResult(PickVisualMedia()){uri ->
    if (uri == null) Toast.makeText(this, R.string.selectPhoto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    else binding.image.setImageURI(uri)
}
binding.image.setOnClickListener {
    pickPhoto.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))
}
```

я получаю URI изображения, выбранного пользователем, и ставлю его в `imageView`, однако, я бы хотел сохранить его в файлы приложения, чтобы его можно было использовать также в `imageView` и сохранять путь в базе данных